# PHP access system - OR in function

Tags: php, mysql

i'm trying to make easy user access system.

i have class and function:

```
public static function hasaccess($nid)
{
    self::onlylogged();
    if (isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
        $sessionid = $_SESSION['userid'];
    }else{
        return FALSE;
        die();
    }
    global $pdo;
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT `access` FROM `users` WHERE `id` = :userid LIMIT 1');
    $stmt->bindValue( ':userid', $sessionid);   
    $stmt->execute();
    #return $stmt;
    #$accesarray[];
    if($stmt->rowCount() > 0 && !empty($stmt)){
        $key = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $aid = explode(';', $key['access']);
        $aid = array_filter($aid);

        if (in_array($nid, $aid)) {
            return TRUE;
        }else
        {
            return FALSE;
        }


    }
    else{ 
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

in mysql user access was saving that: 5;7;8;9
i use this in code that:

```
if (user::hasaccess('1' || '7')) {
    echo "yes";
}
else
{
    echo "not";
}
```

Problem is when user have only access '7' not '1'. 
Script return not.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
if (user::hasaccess('1' || '7')) {
   echo "yes";
}
```

to this:

```
if ( user::hasaccess('1') || user::hasaccess('7') ) {
   echo "yes";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your argument to your class is `'1' || '7'`, which evaluates to `true`. In PHP terms that's a value of `1`, so `'1'` succeeds where `'7'` will fail. You need to make two calls to your method, one for each value.

Alternatively, change your method so it can handle the sort of query you're trying to make. You'll need to change the parameters in either case.